# R: Altering the scale of the x-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

guys I have used the code:

```
Combine_mean %>% ggplot(aes(x=factor(Year), y=Length, colour=gender, group=gender)) + geom_line()
```

Which has produce a comprehensive graph, x-axis is however cluttered, listing every year from 1674 to 1834. I would prefer to display this in 10 year increments, would I need to adjust my initial data frame and so the results for the lines for both male and female or could this be done through editing the code above.

[image: I have attached a picture of the graph for context.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should alleviate the issue (I have used dummy data):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Data
Combine_mean <- data.frame(Year=c(seq(1674,1834),seq(1674,1834)),
                           gender=c(rep('female',161),rep('male',161)),
                           Length=c(cumsum(rnorm(161)),cumsum(rnorm(161))))
#Code
Combine_mean %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Year), y=Length, colour=gender, group=gender)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=as.character(seq(1674,1834,by=10)))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this produced a much clearer graph. The only issue is that it therefore only used datasets that reflected the ten year increment. Is there anyway around this? I happy with the result if not, just trying to understand the limits of the software as I'm a little green to this all.

Comment: @NickRuss98 You can modify the `seq()` or also check `scale_x_date()` if your proper variable is a date, these are some tricks that can help you to understand the scope of the plot :)